# Dynamic Button with time Itervals

Tags: java, android, xml

as a follow-up to my first Question and which has been kindly answered by George Mulligan,

I´m trying to create a Button that needs to be pressed 3 times consecutively for it to be avtivated. Between each hit a countdown on the button shows the remaining number of hits for it to become active [Hence after the 1st hit, the button will show 2, after the 2nd will show 1 and after the 3rd lights up green and says Active]

though there should be a timer runnning in the background or some sort of delay that initiates after the first hit and reinitiates after each except for the third when the button has already become active.

When a certain maximum delay is reached before the next hit, the button shall turn back to its original state and one would have to start all over, i.e perform  3 consecutive hits within Time for the Button to become active.

How do I go about that?

So far, I´ve made the button change for 1 hit and setup a .postdelayed() method.

Though that should be overridden and reset following another hit and finally disactivated on the 3rd hit.

Who can tell me how to achieve that?

Is there an UNLESS statement that will allow me to do that?

Here´s my code:

MainActivity.java

```
package button.tutorials.suvendu.com.mybuttontutorial;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Timer timer;
    MyTimerTask myTimerTask;

    Button CoolButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        CoolButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnchangedisp);
        CoolButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View vw) {
                CoolButton.setText(getString(R.string.FirstClick));

                CoolButton.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        CoolButton.setText(getString(R.string.button));
                    }
                }, 1000);


//THIS IS HOW FAR I GOT. THE REST IS STANDARD CODE. 

                timer = new Timer();
                myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();



            }
        });
    }

    class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run(){



        }
        }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }




}
```

and xml file to which it refers to:

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="button.tutorials.suvendu.com.mybuttontutorial.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">



    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button"
        android:id="@+id/btnchangedisp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="128dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use counter for count your hit and check condition of hit and use postDelayed method.

```
     int count = 0;
CoolButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                count = count + 1;// initialise int variable global like int count = 0;

                if (count == 3) {
                    count = 0;// Reset the counter when you got activate.
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your Button is Activated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 // write code here of activate button color change or methods and whatever you want .

                  } else if (count == 2) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your click one more time to activate button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if (count == 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your click two more time to activate button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }, 5000);// this is you delay time , with in 5 second you have to click 3 time otherwise it will again reset counter zero.
                // you can set you time interval to restart counter.
            }

        });
```

Comment: Thx!! that´s exactly what I was looking for. Just one quick one top, when the   button becomes active, what expression could I add for it to remain active or not be anymore affected by the .postdelayed ?

Comment: sorry. I see flaws with this and I didn´t get a full solution :(